# Heroku timeout for Lightning Web Runtime SPA loading the LWC resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, heroku, lwr

I have a single page application built using lightning web runtime (lwr) that pulls in lwc resources to leverage base components. Everything is deployed and works as expected except for the first time heroku starts up it will timeout, and then several minutes later it's working fine. Is there a caching mechanism I can use for the lwc resources or what is the best practice? Let me know if I should provide any more details, thanks in advance for taking a look!

Comment: Same here, not able to understand either. Even locally it's slow (but not as slow) and no log anywhere about what's happening.

Comment: @FabienTaillon I will reproduce with logs and more detail benchmarking the local vs deployed timeout issue. will edit my original question

Comment: If you know how to display more logs let me know, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the environment variable `WARMUP = true`?  This will pre-compile the site on server start up.

Comment: How should we do that ?  Create a .env file ? I tried it and did not see any difference, should we change anything to the lwr.config.json file ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there documentation for the WARMUP variable? I tried adding and have seen no difference

Comment: @kevin-bauer If you want to repro I have a demo (and related heroku app) here: https://github.com/FabienTaillon/lwc-lwr-oss

Comment: @kevin-bauer same here,  added WARMUP variable and couldn't see any difference. Is there a way to get the generated static files somewhere ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon I am going to take a look at your repo and see if I can suggest you to better use static gen...

Comment: @FabienTaillon. I have created a fork of your repo that adds static gen to your site ->https://github.com/kmbauer/lwc-lwr-oss

npm run build <-- to static gen the site
npm run start:static <-- to server your site statically

Note I move all your dependencies to dev dependencies.  npm install --omit=dev would run a smaller production footprint (If full static would cover your needs).

Comment: This is now working super fast, thank you very much for the help here @KevinBauer !